# How to animate position of a Bootstrap element on width resize (like Masonry)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 3 column Bootstrap layout (with divs floating left with a width of 33.33%). I have a button that toggles this to a 2 column layout as such:

```
$("#toggle-btn").clickToggle(function() {
   //MAKE 2 COLS
   $(".col-md-4").stop().animate({width: "50%"}, 500);
}, function() {
   //BACK TO 3 COLS
   $(".col-md-4").stop().animate({width: "33.33%"}, 500);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">I'm a column</a>
  <div class="col-md-4">I'm a column</a>
  <div class="col-md-4">I'll appear on a 2nd row when the toggle is hit</a>
  <div class="col-md-4">I'm a column</a>
</div>
```

This works fine, but it looks pretty chunky. The 3rd column just appears and disappears when the toggle is clicked. I'd like to animate animate the `.col-md-4` elements when they change positions and need to go on a 2nd line.

I've tried using Masonry to achieve this but with no success - it doesn't seem to like column widths as percentages. I'd like to be able to create the animation part myself to have more control over it.

I'm not sure about how to go about achieving this myself. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Edit: I am after an effect similar to how the Blue 'Search' box behaves in this example (resize browser):

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tynas

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?  Note, it seems to work a little better in full screen view.  I'm sure you could do something nicer by adjusting the timings.

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

$("#toggle-btn").clickToggle(function() {

  $("#target.col-xs-4")
    .stop()
    .animate({width: "0%"}, 900)
    .animate({width: "50%"}, 500);

  $(".col-xs-4").not("#target")
    .stop()
    .animate({width: "50%"}, 1000);
  
}, function() {

  $(".col-xs-4").not("#target")
    .stop()
    .animate({width: "33.33%"}, 1000);

  $("#target.col-xs-4")
    .stop()
    .animate({width: "0%"}, 900)
    .animate({width: "33.33%"}, 500);

});
```

```css
.col-xs-4 {
  border: solid 1px;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;"><button id="toggle-btn">toggle</button></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">I'm a column</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">I'm a column</a></div>
    <div id="target" class="col-xs-4">2nd row when the toggled</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">I'm a column</a></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close! But I need a more dynamic way of identifying the 3rd element (live version will have a dynamic or infinite number of elements so I cannot use nth child to identify them).

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are potentially **many** cells, I would recommend against an animation now.  You might try fading the cells, swapping the class (or set the width manually) then fade in.

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

$("#toggle-btn").clickToggle(function() {

  $(".col-xs-4").fadeOut(500, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass("col-xs-4")
    $this.addClass("col-xs-6")
    $this.fadeIn(500);
  });
 
}, function() {

  $(".col-xs-6").fadeOut(500, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass("col-xs-6")
    $this.addClass("col-xs-4")
    $this.fadeIn(500);
  });

});
```

```css
.col-xs-4, .col-xs-6 {
  border: solid 1px;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;"><button id="toggle-btn">toggle</button></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">column a</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">column b</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">column c</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">column d</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">column e</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">column f</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">column g</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">column h</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```